# telegram bot (aiogram 3+) doesn't handle inline-buttons fsr

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

Telegram bot (aiogram 3+) doesn't handle inline-buttons fsr. Here is how my inline-keyboard is created:

```
class KeyboardCreator:

    @staticmethod
    async def create_meetings_inline_keyboard(meetings: dict, timezone_shift=3) -> InlineKeyboardMarkup:
        kb = []
        current_time = datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(hours=timezone_shift)
        for meeting in meetings["meetings"]:
            if meeting['paid'] == '1' and meeting['status'].lower() == 'planned':
                meeting_time = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(int(meeting['date'])) + timedelta(hours=timezone_shift)
                if meeting_time > current_time:
                    formatted_date = meeting_time.strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M')
                    button_text = f"{formatted_date} - {meeting['specialistFirstName']} {meeting['specialistLastName']}"
                    callback_data = f"meeting:{meeting['id']}"
                    logger.debug({callback_data})
                    kb.append([InlineKeyboardButton(text=button_text, callback_data=callback_data)])
        keyboard = InlineKeyboardMarkup(inline_keyboard=kb)
        return keyboard
```

Here is how i'm trying to catch callbackquery (meeting:ID) for different states:

```
@router.callback_query(MessageManager.waiting_for_consultation, F.data.startswith('meeting:'))
async def meeting_button_callback_handler(call: CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    logger.debug('button pressed')
    await call.message.answer('Input the message, pls')

    await state.set_state(MessageManager.waiting_for_message)


@router.callback_query(FileManager.waiting_for_meeting, F.data.startswith('meeting:'))
async def meeting_button_callback_handler_2(call: CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    logger.debug('button pressed')

    await call.message.answer('Pls, input the file you want to send to the host')

    await state.set_state(FileManager.waiting_for_file)
```

But when i press on generated kb - telegram is not handling it.
Here is how i register routers:

```
dp.include_routers(
        start.router,
        sendmessage.router,
        my_consultations.router,
        upload.router,
        callback_query_handlers.router,
        about.router,
        authorisation.router,
        get_results.router
    )
```

Here is how i use KeyboardCreator and how i set states:

```
@router.message(StateFilter(None), F.text == '✉️ Send Message')
async def sendmessage_button_handler(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    user_id = message.from_user.id

    await message.answer(text='Pls, wait',
                         allow_sending_without_reply=True)
    await async_db_manager.create_pool()
    email = await async_db_manager.fetch_email_by_user_id(user_id=user_id)

    if not email:
        logger.error(f'Email is not filled or doesnt exist for user: {user_id}')
        return

    meetings = await user_auth_client.get_user_meetings(tg_id=user_id, email=email)
    logger.debug(str(meetings))

    formatted_message = await Formatter.parse_paid_meetings(meetings=meetings)
    await message.answer(formatted_message)

    inline_keyboard = await KeyboardCreator.create_meetings_inline_keyboard(meetings=meetings)

    await message.answer(text='Choose a meeting, pls', reply_markup=inline_keyboard)

    current_state = await state.get_state()
    logger.debug(f"Current state before button press: {current_state}")

    await state.set_state(MessageManager.waiting_for_consultation)

    logger.debug('state waiting_for_consultation set')
    current_state = await state.get_state()
    logger.debug(f"Current state before button press: {current_state}")
```

I tried to change bot token, tried to simplify callback_data. Nothing is working. Telegram is not handling clicks on inline-buttons. Pls, help me :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in setting up the webhook. Here is the result of using **getWebhookInfo** method:

```
webhook_info = await bot.get_webhook_info()
logger.debug(webhook_info)
```

**[DEBUG 03/22/2024 16:40:06,849 PM] url='mysite.com' has_custom_certificate=True pending_update_count=0 ip_address='1.1.1.1.1'last_error_date=No Last_error_message=No Last_synchronization_error_date=No max_connections =40 allowed_updates=['message']**

At first, the list of allowed_updates only contained “message”, so it was impossible to get updates of the callback_query type. Here's how I solved this problem: I changed the operating mode of my bot to polling, clicked inline-buttons, returned to the webhook.
Here's the new result of using

```
webhook_info = await bot.get_webhook_info()
logger.debug(webhook_info):
```

**bot_1      | [DEBUG 2024-03-22 16:40:06,849] url='' has_custom_certificate=True pending_update_count=0 ip_address='' last_error_date=None last_error_message=None last_synchronization_error_date=None max_connections=40 allowed_updates=['message', 'callback_query']**

List of allowed updates changed. Inline-keyboards now work as expected.